# Can I post a non-profit challenge that I made?

Tags: discussion, scope

Can I post a non-question post in StackOverflow which promote a coding cyber challenge which I made?
My challenge:

1. Is not profitable.
2. Might contains ads (for the prize, see (3)).
3. Might offer a prize for the first solver.

Comment: No, that would not be appropriate.

Comment: A better place might be r/programming on reddit, I don't think they'll dislike a non-profit coding challenge (i.e. the goal isn't to (ab)use programmers). Then again, the voting patterns are so unpredictable that you may be downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: Side note: "non-profit" and "not profitable" are two very different things... The fact you could not figure out how to make money (or some other benefit) from something ("not profitable") does not make whole thing charitable ("non-profit").

Answer (score 9):

No. On Stack Overflow, questions are just that: questions. If your question is not a question, it will be closed and/or deleted. If you try to get around this by asking "can you guys take a look at this challenge I made?" then that will be closed/deleted as well.

You *may* have better luck on [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), if you follow their rules. If you decide to go that route, you should first post your challenge in [The Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/11066) there.